# Converting data type factor to data type numeric

Tags: r

I have a 11x1 column data frame that was transposed from a 1x11 row data frame. In the row data frame, some elements are `strings` and some elements are `numeric`. When transposed, all elements become `factors`. I want to export this data to excel, without having to convert the data to numerical values in excel.

I have tried converting the formerly numeric values individually back to numeric values with

1. `D4[3,1] <- as.numeric(D4[3,1])`
2. `D4[3,1] <- as.numeric(as.character(D4[3,1]))`
3. `D4[3,1] <- as.numeric(levels(D4[3,1]))[D4[3,1]]`

```
D4 <- data.frame(3, 5, 7)
D4s <- sum(D4[1,1],D4[1,2],D4[1,3])
D4prcnt <- 100*D4/D4s
D4 <- data.frame("NA","NA",D4)
D4prcnt <- data.frame("NA","NA",D4prcnt)
D4 <- as.data.frame(t(D4))
D4prcnt <- as.data.frame(t(D4prcnt))
```

After trying any conversion methods I have stated before, I would expect `class(D4[3,1])` to be `numeric`, but the output is `factor`. Additionally, some of those conversion methods will convert my desired value to `<NA>`, still with `levels 3, 5, 7, NA`.

Comment: Use `stringsAsFactors = FALSE` in the `data.frame/as.data.frame`, then you can convert with `type.convert(D4prcnt))`

Comment: you can also use `D4[] = apply(D4,2,as.numeric)`

Comment: It might help to also point out that once you have a data frame column that is a factor you can't change the type of individual, single elements in that column. You could convert the whole column to numeric, but that's it.

Comment: Can I have column in a data frame with elements of differing class? Now my numerical values are converted to characters, which is the same problem as having them as factors. It seems you can't change element class of individual elements in a column, even if they aren't factors. Excel cannot by default work with those values without first converting them by hand, which is annoying, and I want my user to not have to do that. Additionally, if I convert my column to numeric, excel reads a numeric NA as a blank, and I would like to have NAs present for more a presentable data table.

Comment: No, you can not have a column in a dataframe with differing classes.  All the values in each column are converted to the same class.  In your case, both the numeric and character values are demoted to character class.